# Declaring function with closure in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I want to create a function with completion like in this code. So the function should get a `message` and a completion block.

```
QMServicesManager.instance().chatService.chatAttachmentService.getImageForAttachmentMessage(message, completion: {
              [weak self] (error: NSError?, image: UIImage?) -> Void in

              guard attachmentCell.attachmentID == attachment.ID else {
                return
              }

              self?.attachmentCellsMap.removeObjectForKey(attachment.ID)

              guard error == nil else {
                // TODO - ui. show error later
                //SVProgressHUD.showErrorWithStatus(error!.localizedDescription)
                print("Error downloading image from server: \(error).localizedDescription")
                return
              }

              if image == nil {
                print("Image is nil")
              }

              attachmentCell.setAttachmentImage(image)
              cell.updateConstraints()

              })
          }
```

In objective-c it is simple declared as:

```
- (void)getImageForAttachmentMessage:(QBChatMessage *)attachmentMessage completion:(void(^)(NSError *error, UIImage *image))completion
```

I want the same function in Swift and how to actually process this block.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it precise, I think you want it like this:

```
func getImageForAttachmentMessage(attachmentMessage : QBChatMessage, completion: (error: NSError?, image: UIImage) -> Void) -> Void{
    //code goes here
    let error = NSError(domain: "domain", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    completion(error: error, image: UIImage(named: "sample")!)
}
```